# Is it necessary to create gen_server implementation from auto-create skeletons code?

Tags: elixir

I have used emacs for developing `erlang`. The `gen_server` file is modified after skeletons code has been created.

The following is emacs's `erlang`'s skeleton codes, it is created by by `erlang`'s plugin for emacs.

When trying to writing the first elixir's gen_server, I can't find this skeleton function is vscode's `elixir` plugin.

So I wonder whether it is necessary to do the same routine as before? If not, why, if yes, how?

```
-module(****).

-behaviour(gen_server).

%% API
-export([start_link/0]).

%% gen_server callbacks
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2,
         terminate/2, code_change/3]).

-define(SERVER, ?MODULE).

-record(state, {}).

%%%===================================================================
%%% API
%%%===================================================================

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @doc
%% Starts the server
%%
%% @spec start_link() -> {ok, Pid} | ignore | {error, Error}
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, ?SERVER}, ?MODULE, [], []).

%%%===================================================================
%%% gen_server callbacks
%%%===================================================================

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @private
%% @doc
%% Initializes the server
%%
%% @spec init(Args) -> {ok, State} |
%%                     {ok, State, Timeout} |
%%                     ignore |
%%                     {stop, Reason}
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
init([]) ->
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    {ok, #state{}}.

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @private
%% @doc
%% Handling call messages
%%
%% @spec handle_call(Request, From, State) ->
%%                                   {reply, Reply, State} |
%%                                   {reply, Reply, State, Timeout} |
%%                                   {noreply, State} |
%%                                   {noreply, State, Timeout} |
%%                                   {stop, Reason, Reply, State} |
%%                                   {stop, Reason, State}
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
handle_call(_Request, _From, State) ->
    Reply = ok,
    {reply, Reply, State}.

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @private
%% @doc
%% Handling cast messages
%%
%% @spec handle_cast(Msg, State) -> {noreply, State} |
%%                                  {noreply, State, Timeout} |
%%                                  {stop, Reason, State}
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
handle_cast(_Msg, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @private
%% @doc
%% Handling all non call/cast messages
%%
%% @spec handle_info(Info, State) -> {noreply, State} |
%%                                   {noreply, State, Timeout} |
%%                                   {stop, Reason, State}
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
handle_info(_Info, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @private
%% @doc
%% This function is called by a gen_server when it is about to
%% terminate. It should be the opposite of Module:init/1 and do any
%% necessary cleaning up. When it returns, the gen_server terminates
%% with Reason. The return value is ignored.
%%
%% @spec terminate(Reason, State) -> void()
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ok.

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @private
%% @doc
%% Convert process state when code is changed
%%
%% @spec code_change(OldVsn, State, Extra) -> {ok, NewState}
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.

%%%===================================================================
%%% Internal functions
%%%===================================================================

_—
```

`Emacs`'s skeleton menu is in the following picture.
[image]

Is it necessary for `elixir` programming? If yes, how to do it in vscode?

```
defmodule XXXX do
  @moduledoc false
  use GenServer
  require Logger

  def start_link(_opts) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  @impl true
  def init(:ok) do
    {:ok, :unused_state}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_info({:info, msg, file, line}, state) do
    Logger.info(msg, domain: [:xla], file: file, line: line)
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_info({:warning, msg, file, line}, state) do
    Logger.warning(msg, domain: [:xla], file: file, line: line)
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_info({:error, msg, file, line}, state) do
    Logger.error(msg, domain: [:xla], file: file, line: line)
    {:noreply, state}
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you please re-state the question? One needs to create `GenServer` implementation if they need a `GenServer`. In all the languages/environments implementations get created by writing code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike plain Erlang, Elixir leverages metaprogramming and defines all optional callbacks that aren't provided when you call `use GenServer`, reducing the boilerplate. As mentioned in the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#module-example), the only required callback is `init/1`.

Regarding vscode, you can use [snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) to generate code. You can either define your own, or reach for existing plugins like this [one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=florinpatrascu.vscode-elixir-snippets).